# Is synchronization a domain concern or should it be in the data access layer?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am developing an application that displays a list of current work-orders to users.  This list is 'live' in that it should automatically update whenever changes are made behind-the-scenes.

I am at the point where I need to implement the synchronization logic to keep the data in the list in-sync.  I am abstracting away the actual mechanism driving synchronization (e.g. polling, event-driven, etc.) so we can change approaches as needed but am stuck determining if this logic belongs in the domain layer or data layer.

Should data synchronization as described be 'hidden' in the data layer or is it a domain concern and belongs in that layer?

Answer (score 1):

Not domain layer in my personal expierence. Because it's highly coupled with the ui interface. Do you still need this mechanism if the work-orders list doesn't need to be 'live'? Domain models should be relatively stable (unless the domain changes), not be driven by ui and applications.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't really thought about that.  We actually split our UX into UI and Presentation layers so we can swap UI technologies on top of the same Presentation layer for consistent behavior and a single code-base.  I hadn't considered putting the synchronization mechanism in the presentation layer. Hmmmm...